# How can I make this CheckBox list in asp.net work?

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I started to write some code in Razor Pages, and I want to make a CheckBox list, but this isn't working.
My code from the (page).cshtml.cs file that sets the list:

```
public List<ModelForCheckBoxList> Kontakty = new List<ModelForCheckBoxList>
    {
        new ModelForCheckBoxList{Id = 1, Name = "E-Mail", IsChecked = false },
        new ModelForCheckBoxList{Id = 2, Name = "Telefon", IsChecked = false },
        new ModelForCheckBoxList{Id = 3, Name = "Osobisty", IsChecked = false }
    };
```

My code from the (page).cshtml file that has to show those checkbox'es:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Kontakt)
            @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Kontakty.Count; index++)
                {
                <div class="form-control">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Kontakty[index].Id)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Kontakty[index].IsChecked)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Kontakty[index].Name)
                </div>
                }
        </div>
```

And again from my (page).cshtml.cs where I try to set the chosen checkbox'es on my object:

```
Uczestnik.Kontakt = Kontakty.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

I have no idea why this isn't working. 
Thanks for the help

EDIT: I forgot to say what's wrong. When I set a brak point on

```
Uczestnik.Kontakt = Kontakty.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

it shows that no item in Kontakty has it's isChecked value as true, even if I check it and click send, that code is in a OnPost method

EDIT2: Here I show more of the code

```
public class AnkietaGlownaModel : PageModel
{
    public Uczestnik Uczestnik { get; set; }


    public List<ModelForCheckBoxList> Kontakty = new List<ModelForCheckBoxList>
    {
        new ModelForCheckBoxList{Id = 1, Name = "E-Mail", IsChecked = false },
        new ModelForCheckBoxList{Id = 2, Name = "Telefon", IsChecked = false },
        new ModelForCheckBoxList{Id = 3, Name = "Osobisty", IsChecked = false }
    };

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public ActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();

        Uczestnik.Kontakt = Kontakty.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        return RedirectToPage("/Index", Uczestnik);
    }
}
```

This is from my AnkietaGlowna.cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h4>Ankieta dla klientów</h4></div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: lightgrey">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Imie)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Imie, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Imie, null, new { @class = "text-danger"})
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Plec)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Plec, new[] {

               new SelectListItem()
               {
                   Text = "Mężczyzna",
                   Value = "Mężczyzna"
               },
               new SelectListItem()
               {

                   Text = "Kobieta",
                   Value = "Kobieta"
               },
               new SelectListItem()
               {
                   Text = "Nie podaję",
                   Value = "Nie Podano",
                   Selected = true
               } }, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Email, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.NumerTelefonu)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Uczestnik.NumerTelefonu, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Uczestnik.NumerTelefonu, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Ulica)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Ulica, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.NumerDomu)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Uczestnik.NumerDomu, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.NumerMieszkania)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Uczestnik.NumerMieszkania, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Uczestnik.NumerMieszkania, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.KodPocztowy)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Uczestnik.KodPocztowy, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Uczestnik.KodPocztowy, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Miejscowosc)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Miejscowosc, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Uczestnik.Kontakt)
            @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Kontakty.Count; index++)
                {
                <div class="form-control">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Kontakty[index].Id)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Kontakty[index].IsChecked)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Kontakty[index].Name)
                </div>
                }
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success center-block">Wyślij ankietę</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my ModelForCheckBoxList

```
public class ModelForCheckBoxList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

As I said before the problem is, the Kontakty.IsChecked is not changing, when I check  it in the form and click submit

Comment: "complete", minimum example plz.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{       
        string strChecked = "checked";

        foreach (var item in Model.Kontakty)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" name="SUMBIT NAME" value="@item.Id" @if (item.IsChecked) { @strChecked } />
            <a>@item.Name</a>
        }

}
```